# hover mode on Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is it possible to have the hover activated when you are not hovering over a specific 'point' in a line graph?

I want *that* particular tooltip to activate whenever I hover over any part of the chart.

**Edit:** something like this http://watchstocks.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 20):

Yes, you can use chart.js to configure tooltips to get a similiar behavior to the chart that you referenced.

For more information, check out the [`mode`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-tooltip-configuration) tooltip config option and [hover](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-hover-configuration) config options for your needs.  Here is an example.

```
options: {
  responsive: true,
  title:{
    display:true,
    text:'Chart.js Line Chart'
  },
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false,
  },
 hover: {
    mode: 'nearest',
    intersect: true
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      display: true,
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Month'
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      display: true,
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
      },
    }]
  }
}
```

Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/ZeaLGj) demonstrating the behavior that matches your example.

Answer (score 15):

For chart version > 3 rename the object **tooltips** to **tooltip** and place it inside the **plugin** object.

```
options: {
      plugins: {
                 legend: {
                 display: false
                 },
                 tooltip: {
                 mode: 'index',
                 intersect: false
                 }
      },
      hover: {
             mode: 'nearest',
             intersect: false
             }


}
```

Comment: documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.3.2/configuration/tooltip.html

Answer (score 9):

```
tooltips: {
  mode: 'x-axis'
},
```

^^ That will bring up the tooltip when you hover over any y-axis position. If you only want it to show up when you hover over a point on a line, use this:

```
tooltips: {
  mode: 'label'
},
```