# How can I place single data on the center in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

My code:

```
        var chart = new Chart('graph_data', {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: data.labels.labels,
                datasets: dataSets
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false,
                },
                legend: {
                   display: true,
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        ticks: {
                            autoSkip: true,
                            maxRotation: 0,
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: attributeLabels[data.labels.type],
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

When there is a lot of data, everything is fine.
[image]

But when there is a little data, the points are shifted to the left.
How can I place it on the center? no idea?
[image]

Comment: seems like you need to adjust the X axis based on the single data point?

Comment: @SurajRao Yes, but I can not find the option I need

Comment: @SurajRao can u try to help?

Comment: Hey you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059722/chart-js-hover-labels-to-display-data-for-all-data-points-on-x-axis/56769736#56769736 it will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I fixed this problem a little elsewhere. If it's single data, add empty values without headers to the data array:

```
datapoints = [NaN, 1800, NaN];
labels = ['', 'Label', ''],
```

[image]

Comment: Could be a dirty solution, but this did the trick for me, thanks!